# How do I add permissions to my ls-al c program?

Tags: c, linux, permissions, ls

I am writing code to implement the ls-al command using c program and I have gotten my code to implement it without printing permissions but I want to implement the permissions as well but cant figure out how. any suggestions? my code is below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pwd.h>

// Last Modified
        time_t t = my_stat.st_mtime;
        localtime_r(&t, &lt);
        char timebuf[80];
        strftime(timebuf, sizeof(timebuf), "%c", &lt);
        if (pwd != 0) {
            printf("%s \t %ld \t %s \t %s", pwd->pw_name, (long)my_stat.st_size, timebuf, current_directory->d_name);
            printf("\n");
        } else {
            printf("%d \t %ld \t %s \t %s", my_stat.st_uid, (long)my_stat.st_size, timebuf, current_directory->d_name);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    closedir(directory);
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if ( argc == 1 ) {
        return list_dir ( "." );
    } else {
        int ret = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i += 1 ) {
            if ( list_dir ( argv[i] ) != 0 ) {
                ret = 1;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

I have ben trying for a long time to be able to add permissions to this code but I seem to be getting stuck and am out of ideas here

the output of my code is:

```
kev      0   Thu Jun 20 13:39:49 2019    .
kev      0   Thu Jun 20 13:39:46 2019    ..
kev      24147   Thu Jun 20 12:24:40 2019    CMakeCache.txt
kev      0   Thu Jun 20 13:39:53 2019    CMakeFiles
kev      1426    Thu Jun 20 12:24:41 2019    cmake_install.cmake
kev      5160    Thu Jun 20 12:24:41 2019    Makefile
```

the expected output is:

```
rw-r--r--  1 kev     0   Thu Jun 20 13:39:49 2019    .
rw-r--r--  1 kev     0   Thu Jun 20 13:39:46 2019    ..
-rw-------       24147   Thu Jun 20 12:24:40 2019    CMakeCache.txt
rw-r--r--   kev      0   Thu Jun 20 13:39:53 2019    CMakeFiles
-rw-------  kev      1426    Thu Jun 20 12:24:41 2019 cmake_install.cmake
rw-r--r-- kev    5160    Thu Jun 20 12:24:41 2019    Makefile
```

Comment: I don't see you making use of the `mode_t st_mode` field of your `struct stat`

Comment: what is that mode used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to make use of the `mode_t st_mode` field of your `struct stat`.  See stat(2):

> **The stat structure**
>
> All of these system calls return a stat structure, which contains the following fields:
>
> ```
> struct stat {
>    dev_t     st_dev;         /* ID of device containing file */
>    ino_t     st_ino;         /* inode number */
>    mode_t    st_mode;        /* file type and mode */
>    nlink_t   st_nlink;       /* number of hard links */
>    uid_t     st_uid;         /* user ID of owner */
>    gid_t     st_gid;         /* group ID of owner */
>    dev_t     st_rdev;        /* device ID (if special file) */
>    off_t     st_size;        /* total size, in bytes */
>    blksize_t st_blksize;     /* blocksize for filesystem I/O */
>    blkcnt_t  st_blocks;      /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
>
>    /* Since Linux 2.6, the kernel supports nanosecond
>       precision for the following timestamp fields.
>       For the details before Linux 2.6, see NOTES. */
>
>    struct timespec st_atim;  /* time of last access */
>    struct timespec st_mtim;  /* time of last modification */
>    struct timespec st_ctim;  /* time of last status change */
>
> #define st_atime st_atim.tv_sec      /* Backward compatibility */  
> #define st_mtime st_mtim.tv_sec    #define st_ctime st_ctim.tv_sec    };
> ```

[...]

> **The file type and mode (st_mode)**
>
> POSIX refers to the st_mode bits corresponding to the mask S_IFMT (see below) as the file type, the 12 bits corresponding to the mask 07777 as the file mode bits and the least significant 9 bits (0777) as the file permission
>          bits.
>
> The following mask values are defined for the file type of the st_mode field:
>
> ```
>        S_IFMT     0170000   bit mask for the file type bit field
>
>        S_IFSOCK   0140000   socket
>
>        S_IFLNK    0120000   symbolic link
>        S_IFREG    0100000   regular file
>        S_IFBLK    0060000   block device
>        S_IFDIR    0040000   directory
>        S_IFCHR    0020000   character device
>        S_IFIFO    0010000   FIFO
> ```

[...]

> The following mask values are defined for the file mode component of the st_mode field:
>
> ```
>        S_ISUID     04000   set-user-ID bit
>        S_ISGID     02000   set-group-ID bit (see below)
>        S_ISVTX     01000   sticky bit (see below)
>
>        S_IRWXU     00700   owner has read, write, and execute permission
>        S_IRUSR     00400   owner has read permission
>        S_IWUSR     00200   owner has write permission
>        S_IXUSR     00100   owner has execute permission
>
>        S_IRWXG     00070   group has read, write, and execute permission
>        S_IRGRP     00040   group has read permission
>        S_IWGRP     00020   group has write permission
>        S_IXGRP     00010   group has execute permission
>
>        S_IRWXO     00007   others  (not  in group) have read, write, and execute per‐
>                            mission
>        S_IROTH     00004   others have read permission
>        S_IWOTH     00002   others have write permission
>        S_IXOTH     00001   others have execute permission
> ```

Comment: Thanks this comment really helped! my code is running like it should now